# How to set how far down a page a HTML fragment links to?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, anchor

HTML fragments using links to pages using `/#page-section` to link to a specific section of a page is loading too low down the element for me.

For example I set up a `<div id="engagment">` and then link to `site.com/#engagement` but instead of it linking to the top of the section like this: 
[what I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7Zoh.jpg)

I get this: [What actually happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4MUe.jpg)

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance. I'm new to html/web development.

Comment: Your nav bar is set to a fixed navbar and scrolls with the page. It has infact sent you to the right place but your nav is covering the top of the text. Add padding-top to the inside of your divs equal to the nav height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a fixed header which overlaps that section (which is actually positioned at the top of the window). So you need to create an offset.

A common way is to add an invisible pseudo element to the original target element of the link via CSS, like this:

```
#page-section::before { 
  display: block; 
  content: " "; 
  margin-top: -150px; 
  height: 150px; 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

This will "extend" the element with that ID in a way that causes the anchor to be 150px above the main element, without any other visible changes. Adjust that value as you need it (i.e. to the height of your fixed header)

(A `padding-top` or `margin-top` would do something similar, but it would create an empty space in there, which you might not necessarily want)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me, and the code example you gave is very helpful too. I just want to clarify what is the content: " "; attribute?

I don't know why you were downvoted. That was a helpful answer!

Comment: that pseudo element needs some content to actually appear (although in this case it's invisible since there is no "real" content). In other situations this could be some text, but here you wouldn't want any text, so you just use `content: " ";`

Comment: Thanks. I now just noticed another issue, when I click the link to the fragment and it reloads to that section of the page a blue outline appears areound the div I used as the fragment. Do you know how I can stop this, perhaps some more CSS I need to add? Thank you again. I really appreciate you sharing your time/knowledge.

Comment: I am not completely sure if I understand what you mean, but most likely that's the *focus* which appears around links, form fields etc. when they are "in focus", which is important for accessibility, i.e. to help people who don't use a mouse to select and activate (instead of click) these elements

Comment: You were correct. Thanks. For posterity if anyone else has this problem I added 

    #page-section:focus{
           outline: none;
    }